# Is there a way to set one variable from two possible @Inputs? (Angular2+)

Tags: angular, input

I'm trying to define a set of inputs for a Directive in Angular8 while trying to support a legacy Directive as well. Going forward, I would like to name my inputs in camel-case, but my previous inputs are in kebab-case. So, in support the legacy Directive, I need to know which input is present, and then set a single variable. Note that we can be sure only one input will be present at a time. Essentially, I would like to disable the previous Directive and simultaneously enable the new one without wasting time going back and updating everywhere that directive is called.

Here's how I'd like to call my Directive:

```html
<button ft-targets-modal="modal1">Button</button>
<button ftTargetsModal="modal1">Button</button>
```

Here's what I have so far:

```js
@Directive({
    selector: '[ft-targets-modal],[ftTargetsModal]',
    inputs: ['ftTargetsModal']
})
export class TargetsModal implements OnInit {
    id: string;

    @Input("ft-targets-modal")
    targetsModal: string;
    ftTargetsModal: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.id = targetsModal || ftTargetsModal;
    }
}
```

This works, but it looks terrible. So I was hoping that one of you would be able to direct me towards a solution that doesn't look nearly as terrible, or something that I'm missing about @Input() or something else.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export class TargetsModal implements OnInit {
    @Input("ftTargetsModal")
    id: string;

    @Input("ft-targets-modal")
    set ftTargetsModal(id: string) {
      this.id = id;
    }
}
```

But unless this directive is part of a public library, I would simply refactor every usage of this directive using a global query-replace.

Comment: I was hoping for something a little closer to @Input("ft-targets-modal", "ftTargetsModal"), but I can't find anything like it.